Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate'
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate' in your configuration.
spring boot-2.7.12
spring-boot-starter-data-redis-2.7.12
spring-data-redis-2.7.12
Added spring-boot-starter-data-redis 2.7.12
updated spring-data-redis version to 2.7.12
still facing the same issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
